# IF function: SQRT equation as value if true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

- I have data for re-sightings of individuals in terms of their X (column G) and Y (column H) co-ordinates and the time (day) recorded in column B.
- I have several thousand data entries and want to manipulate an equation so I can autofill an entire column to plot.

Where time = 0, that is the release point and I want the distance moved column to remain empty. So by using the `IF` function, I want to look at daily movement by calculating the Euclidean distance with a simple pythagoras equation, the `SQRT` function.

The equation I have written is as follows:
`=IF(B2 > 0, "=SQRT(((G2-H2)^2)+((G3-H3)^2))", " ")`

Where t=0, the cells remain empty as I wished. However, instead of providing me with a numerical value according to the equation, it just writes the equation exactly as it appears. When removing the inverted commas I get `TRUE`, so that's not it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the inverted commas AND the equals sign before SQRT. Also, don't use " " for a blank return: instead use "". Your parentheses can also be reduced: =IF(B2>0,SQRT((G2-H2)^2+(G3-H3)^2),"")

Answer (score 1):

Using quotation marks as you did around `"=SQRT(((G2-H2)^2)+((G3-H3)^2))"` means just that, to have the result be the **string** between the quotation marks. What you want is to drop the quotation marks and the `=`:

```
=IF(B2 > 0, SQRT(((G2-H2)^2)+((G3-H3)^2)), "")
```

However, I think you got your formula wrong as you are mixing X and Y. Should it not be:

```
SQRT((G3-G2)^2 + (H3-H2)^2))
```

Also, you might be able to do away with the `IF` altogether by just starting the formula one cell down.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thanks! And yes, that is what the equation should be, I got quite confused. Never really used the IF function all that much, but I think I do need it as I have around 10 sightings for many, many individuals and I want to separate them. Thanks again

Comment: @user25002, Is there anything you still would like me to clarify in the answer before accepting it?